# Script to drop and recreate all tables in a given database in Teradata

Tags: unix, teradata

I have to code a script in Teradata that will accept a database-name as an input parameter and then will `drop` and `re-create` all the tables that exist in the database (ie passed as the input parameter).

If necessary, it is also good to create a `UNIX` script with an input parameter that would log-in to the Teradata server and accomplish the same (drop and then recreate), in which case I would want to log the ddls in a file before dropping and recreating them.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to drop and recreate tables instead of simply deleting the data?

Comment: the tables are huge in size. Deleting data will be time consuming. I can either drop and recreate or Truncate the tables in the database. Best would be automate the process via scripts (in Unix or Teradata procedures)

Comment: `DELETE FROM tab;` is similar to a `TRUNCATE`, if the optimizer knows it will be committed. Search for `DELETE Processing Time` in the *SQL Data Manipulation Language* for your Teradata release